# How to declare an empty NUMERIC variable? (equivalent to "int x;" in java)

Tags: javascript

Given an array with subarrays, I need to return a new array that is made of the largest numbers of the subarrays.

The array:

```
let arr = [[1,2], [10, 15], [30, 40], [-1, -50]];
```

The new array should be:

```
newArr = [2, 40, -1];
```

I've kinda solved it, but it doesn't work for negative numbers as the initial value is 0. 
 How can I declare an empty numeric variable such as "int x;" in java?

```
  let newArr = [0, 0, 0, 0]; // Instead of 0 I need an empty numeric 
  for (let x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
    for (let y = 0; y < arr[x].length; y++) {
      if (newArr[x] < arr[x][y]) {
        newArr[x] = arr[x][y];
      }
    }
  }

console.log(newArr) // 2,15,40,0
```

expected: 2, 15, 40, -1

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have types to the variables - it's dynamic typing, after all. If you have a variable that holds a number, it will be a numeric variable, but you can always reassign it to a string and it will not be a number any more.

Comment: The new array should be: `newArr = [2, 40, -1];` why `15` is not in desired output ?

Comment: Javascript variables aren't strongly typed. The type of the variable is the type of its value. So an empty numeric value doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that `-1` is not smaller than `0`, and so your array will not be updated, instead, start your `newArr` with `-Infinity`s instead of `0` such that any number will be bigger than it like so:

```js
let arr = [
  [1, 2],
  [10, 15],
  [30, 40],
  [-1, -50]
];


let newArr = []; 

for (let x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
  newArr.push(-Infinity); // populate it with `-Infinity`
  for (let y = 0; y < arr[x].length; y++) {
    if (newArr[x] < arr[x][y]) {
      newArr[x] = arr[x][y];
    }
  }
}

console.log(newArr) // 2,15,40,-1
```

Comment: Amazing thanks, setting new arr[x] to -Infinity makes it dynamic and you can check arrays with more than 4 subarrays

Comment: @Makeyka no worries, you can also use the first element of each inner array instead of `-Infinity` (like _Thuvarakan_ has done)

Answer (score 3):

You could take [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) and spread the items.

```js
let array = [[1,2], [10, 15], [30, 40], [-1, -50]],
    max = array.map(a => Math.max(...a));

console.log(max);
```

Comment: Thanks that really helped. I was looking for a more primitive way to somewhat set an empty value such as -Infinity such as the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Empty numeric values wouldn't help you either using your logic, because you are setting wrong initial values for comparison. See this, same as yours, with minor fix:

```
let arr = [[1,2], [10, 15], [30, 40], [-1, -50]];

 let newArr = [arr[0][0], arr[1][0], arr[2][0], arr[3][0]]; 
  for (let x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
    for (let y = 0; y < arr[x].length; y++) {
      if (newArr[x] < arr[x][y]) {
        newArr[x] = arr[x][y];
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the initial value as the 1st element or sub-array.

```js
  
  let arr = [[1,2], [10, 15], [30, 40], [-1, -50]];

  newArr = [] // Instead of 0 I need an empty numeric
  for (let x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
 newArr[x] = arr[x][0]
    for (let y = 0; y < arr[x].length; y++) {
      if (newArr[x] < arr[x][y]) {
        newArr[x] = arr[x][y];
      }
    }
  }

console.log(newArr) // 2,15,40,0
```

Or you can use map function to return the max values.

```js
let arr = [[1,2], [10, 15], [30, 40], [-1, -50]];

let newArr = arr.map(subArr => Math.max(...subArr))

console.log(newArr)
```